# Exclude specs2 as transitive dependency of play framework in sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to use specs2 v3.10.0 with Play Framework v2.2.3 but Play depends on specs2 v2.1.1 and it seems like they are interfering with each other.

In my plugins.sbt file, I have:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.3" exclude("org.specs2", "specs2"))
```

See the [Dependencies file of Play Framework 2.2.x](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/project/Dependencies.scala)

Here is a screenshot of my Ivy resolution cache report showing the two versions of specs2 getting resolved as test dependencies:

[resolution cache report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMog0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Plugin dependencies are not resolved to test dependencies as far as I know.
You probably need to exclude the dependency in the *build.sbt*, not in the *plugins.sbt*.